# Is there a more efficient way of writing this Jsoup code

Tags: jsp, jsoup

I am making a website in jsp to compare prices of products from different shopping websites, and i wrote the code on 1 jsp page in the following way:

```
try
{
 jsoup.connect(first_website)
 /* code for fetching prices and images */
 /* Html code for displaying prices and images */     
} catch(){}

try
{
 jsoup.connect(second_website)
 /* code for fetching prices and images */
 /* Html code for displaying prices and images */
} catch(){}

try
{
 jsoup.connect(third_website)
 /* code for fetching prices and images */
 /* Html code for displaying prices and images */
} catch(){}
```

This code displays results from three website on same page for a single search query. But the problem is that my website is now loading slowly and some times results from one or the other websites are not displayed. It gives me following error:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL.Status=500,URL=/*websitename*/
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use multiple threads to request sites, so you will send requests to the sites simultaneously.

you can do this will java Task Executor Service like this:

```
    FutureTask<Boolean> futureTask1 = new FutureTask<Boolean>(new Callable<Boolean>()
    {
        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception
        {
            try
            {
                //jsoup.connect(second_website)
                 /* code for fetching prices and images */
                 /* Html code for displaying prices and images */
                return true;
            } catch(Exception e){
                return false;
            }

        }
    });

    FutureTask<Boolean> futureTask2 = new FutureTask<Boolean>(new Callable<Boolean>()
    {
        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception
        {
            //Same as above
        }
    });

    FutureTask<Boolean> futureTask3 = new FutureTask<Boolean>(new Callable<Boolean>()
    {
        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception
        {
            //Same as above
        }
    });

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    executorService.execute(futureTask1);
    executorService.execute(futureTask2);
    executorService.execute(futureTask3);

    while (true){
        if(futureTask1.isDone() && futureTask2.isDone() && futureTask3.isDone()){
            //Here work is done
            try
            {
                if(futureTask1.get()){
                    //task 1 done it's work correctly
                }else {
                    //some problem in task 
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And if you have common logic between these tasks, you can create a class that implements `Callable` interface and pass sites url to its constructor.